# localStorage is deleted after I use BACK button (All browsers)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage

I have implemented localStorage for some data that is useful for user experience, but is NOT essential for application itself (doesn't break functionality).

**Problem**: Every time I go to show page and then press BACK button to INDEX page all my local storage disappears.

localStorage is set in INDEX page with function:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 return $(".sort_link").on("ajax:success", function(e, data, status, xhr) {

             localStorage.removeItem('results');   //removes any old localStorage values



       if (document.getElementById("results-dupl")) {

                 var results = $("#results-dupl").html();   
                 localStorage.results = results           

        } else {

                 var results = $("#searc_re").html();   
                 localStorage.results = results            


        }
  }).on("ajax:error", function(e, xhr, status, error) {

  });

});
```

Basically, localStorage key is set independently, NOT before leaving current INDEX page.

Problem doesn't occur if I press any other link that redirects to INDEX page. I have tried and the same problem occurs on Firefox and Chrome so I guess - on all browsers.

**What I have tried:**

1) Added `localStorage.getItem('results');` right after setting localStorage key as seen in other question.

2) Double checked that above seen function actually creates localStorage key- Yes, 100 % creates.

3) It seems that also cookie that is created within the same INDEX page is lost after visiting show page and then with "BACK" button getting back to INDEX page.

Thanks in advance for any help.

**EDIT:**

Found solution based on accepted answer.

Basically, somehow previously commented out script was working and deleting localStorage and cookies:

```
  localStorage.removeItem('menu');   
  localStorage.removeItem('results');  
  document.cookie = "menu_storage=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC";
```

Comment: What ajax calls are happening that might trigger those handlers? Are you running any on page load? (You haven't shown any.)

Comment: You don't ever show retrieving the storage. Code shown is not enough for anyone to troubleshoot problem from. Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: @charlietfl  , I didn't show retrieving the storage because I am checking its existence in Chrome - Application - Local storage

Comment: Well you clearly have other localStorage code somewhere and what is shown is not enough for us to know anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use `localStorage.removeItem('results');`. it'll fix the problem and `localStorage.removeItem('results');` is useless anyway in this case because you can **edit localStorage instead of deleting it**.

Comment: Why would this have anyting to do with the back button? No ajax has completed that would run that removeItem call (as far as we can tell from the question).

Comment: Because if you back in the page where there is 'localStorage.removeItem('results');' of course it'will be deleted. Also why should you use it when you can edit the value?

Comment: *"of course it'will be deleted"* **Again**: Why? The call isn't unconditional. It's inside an `ajax:success` callback. What ajax, exactly? None is shown being initiated by the `ready` handler in the question.

Comment: @paolo.basso99  I am not an true expert, but that `localStorage.removeItem('results');` is executed only when AJAX success happens, not on every page load.

Comment: Yes you could be right but i can't say without seeing the whole script so try this and if it doesn't work say it to me and I'll delete the answer

Comment: Still the fact that you do not need to delete localstorage  every time

Comment: @paolo.basso99 Actually, your answer was very usefull. I found previusly commented out script that deleted local storage and cookie. I don't know how that script was uncomented..